# Creating excel file using using apache POI for download

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

I have create an excel file using apache poi. Everything is fine. Generally file gets download normally but 1 out of 10 times when i open the file directly from pop-up window (without saving), some totally garbage characters displayed on the browser.

I am using the download code given below

```
OutputStream out = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
servletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
    + excelFileName+".xls");
servletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
excelWorkBook.write(out);
out.close();
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Not enough information.  Screenshots of the "garbage" would be very useful.  Is the file opening in Excel and displaying garbage?

Comment: After `execlWorkBook.write(out)`, add `out.flush()` and see what happens.

Comment: nope. just some random characters on the browser with no style. like it accidentally opened on browser without using ms-excel.

Comment: Does it happen with different browsers, or is just a specific browser showing the error? This could as well be a browser problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison : I am adding the screenshot of my browser displaying the garbage characters. please take a look.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: out.flush() didn't slove the problem :(

Comment: This looks like the browser isn't receiving the content-type header.  If you can reproduce this reliably, watch the traffic using Fiddler or Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see what is actually being sent from the server.